# Populate a bash array with list of particular file types in a directory

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

```
shopt -s nullglob
array=(*)
```

Am I right in thinking that the purpose of the first line (`shopt -s nullglob`) is that in the event that there are unmatched patterns, they aren't added to the array?

I have a directory called unsorted_files.
Now, were I use to `array=(*)`
Am I right in assuming that is a wildcard, and would return ANY file?
If then I were to specify `array=(~/unsorted_files/"*jpg")`

Would that then mean, all jpg files within the unsorted_files directory would then be added to the array and populate them as such as elements?

I have put `"/*jpg"`  in between the `""` but have been advised that this can cause the code to be ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the presence of `"` double-quotes prevents the shell globbing to be done. You need to populate the array without it. Also you need to use glob expression as `*.jpg` to match the `jpg` image extension files.

```
shopt -s nullglob
array=(~/unsorted_files/*.jpg)
```